# Summation of Binomial Distribution 2

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

So we have

$\sum _{k=0}^n\binom{n\:}{k}\:\left(0.3\right)^k\left(0.7\right)^{n-k} = (0.3+0.7)^n=1^n=1$

Now I want to solve

$\sum _{k=\frac{n}{2}+2}^n\binom{n\:}{k}\:\left(0.3\right)^k\left(0.7\right)^{n-k}$

This is what I tried doing

$\sum _{k=0}^n\binom{n\:}{k}\:\left(0.3\right)^k\left(0.7\right)^{n-k}=\sum _{k=\frac{n}{2}+2}^n\binom{n\:}{k}\:\left(0.3\right)^k\left(0.7\right)^{\frac{n}{2}+2-k} +\sum _{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}+1}\binom{\frac{n}{2}+1\:}{k}\:\left(0.3\right)^k\left(0.7\right)^{\frac{n}{2}+1-k}=1 $

$\sum _{k=\frac{n}{2}+2}^n\binom{\frac{n}{2}+2\:}{k}\:\left(0.3\right)^k\left(0.7\right)^{\frac{n}{2}+2-k}= 1-\sum _{k=0}^j\binom{j\:}{k}\:\left(0.3\right)^k\left(0.7\right)^{j-k}, j=\frac{n}{2}+1$

$\sum _{k=\frac{n}{2}+2}^n\binom{\frac{n}{2}+2\:}{k}\:\left(0.3\right)^k\left(0.7\right)^{\frac{n}{2}+2-k}= 1-1^{\frac{n}{2}+1}=0$

Now this is obviously wrong so I am not sure how to make it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $$\sum _{k=0}^n\binom{n\:}{k}\:\left(0.3\right)^k\left(0.7\right)^{n-k}=1$$
if $n$ is even
$$S=\sum _{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}-1}\binom{n\:}{k}\:\left(0.3\right)^k\left(0.7\right)^{n-k}=\sum _{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n\binom{n\:}{k}\:\left(0.3\right)^k\left(0.7\right)^{n-k}$$

leaving one term in between $$\binom{n\:}{\frac{n}{2}}\:\left(0.3\right)^k\left(0.7\right)^{n-\frac{n}{2}}$$

$$S+S+\binom{n\:}{\frac{n}{2}}\:\left(0.3\right)^k\left(0.7\right)^{n-\frac{n}{2}}=1$$
if $n$ is odd

$$\sum _{k=0}^{\frac{2n-1}{2}}\binom{n\:}{k}\:\left(0.3\right)^k\left(0.7\right)^{n-k}=\sum _{k=\frac{2n+1}{2}}^n\binom{n\:}{k}\:\left(0.3\right)^k\left(0.7\right)^{n-k}$$

Comment: So James, the tactic here is to leave out 1 term so that we have something like, $2X=1-Y$ and $X=\frac{(1-Y)}{2}$ so we only have to solve for Y which is the term that was left out when solving for X? I am not quite sure on why if n is even those two summations would be equal, could you elaborate please?

Comment: you got it @glockm15  :)

Comment: oh I think it know, the distribution is symmetric

Comment: read about Pascal triangle and how sums are hidden in Pascal triangle you will understand binomial better

Comment: This is incorrect; the summation is not symmetric in $n$, as $0.3^k0.7^{n-k}\neq 0.3^{n-k}0.7^k$

Comment: but I never wrote the above line what I wrote is  $$S=\sum _{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}-1}\binom{n\:}{k}\:\left(0.3\right)^k\left(0.7\right)^{n-k}=\sum _{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n\binom{n\:}{k}\:\left(0.3\right)^k\left(0.7\right)^{n-k}$$

I never used the term $$ 0.3^{n-k}0.7^k$$